# How to access pointer to pointer values in python?

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I have this python pointer declaration:

```
numberOfThings = ctypes.c_int32()
indexes = ctypes.c_int32()
```

If I print values:

```
print numberOfThings.value
print indexes.value
```

I got:

```
0
0
```

I do the function call:

```
the_Dll.doSomeThing(ctypes.byref(numberOfThings), ctypes.byref(indexes))
```

If I print values now:

```
print "numberOfThings values", numberOfThings.value
print "indexes values", indexes.value
```

I got:

```
numberOfThings values 3
indexes values 147107816
```

The indexes is a pointer to a pointer, but how do I get the value of indexes? My goal is to loop through nr of numberOfThings and for every numberOfThings print the value of indexes like this:

```
for i in range(numberOfThings.value):
    print 'Value of indexes', how to access indexes real value?
```

Do anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the use case where something like this is required or adds clarity? Happy to read further.

Comment: I'm accessing an function in a DLL file. This function will check nr of busses connected to the computer and description about the busses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python's [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html):

> Pointer instances are created by calling the pointer() function on a ctypes type:

```
 >>>
 >>> from ctypes import *
 >>> i = c_int(42)
 >>> pi = pointer(i)
 >>>
```

> **Pointer** instances have a **contents** attribute which returns the object to which the pointer points, the i object above:

```
 >>>
 >>> pi.contents 
 c_int(42)
 >>>
```

So if I properly understood your problem, you should:

1. Use **`pointer`** instead of **`int32`** type
2. Access the pointer content (a.k.a. *dereferencing* the pointer) through the **`variable.contents`** attribute.

### Update

Follow up of our last comments, here the formatted version of your possible solution:

```
numberOfThings = ctypes.c_int32() 
indexes = ctypes.c_void_p() 

_Dll.doSomeThing(ctypes.byref(numberOfThings),ctypes.byref(indexes)) 

ptrt = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double*numberOfThings.value) 
mydblPtr = cast(indexes, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double*numberOfThings.value)) 

indexes = ptrt(mydblPtr.contents)

for content in indices.contents:
    print content
```

Comment: Thx! When I try access the pointer content I got `AttributeError: 'c_void_p' object has no attribute 'contents'`. Maybe I have forget some import..? Is it not enough with `from ctypes import *`?

Comment: You should cast the `c_void_p` against the right type:

`mydblPtr = cast(myVoidVal, POINTER(c_double))`

considering `myVoidVal` the `c_void_p` instance and `c_double` the type of your pointer (the type of `indexes`). In this case `mydblPtr` will have the `contents` attribute.

Comment: If I understand you correct, could I do it like this?:

`numberOfThings = ctypes.c_int32()
indexes = ctypes.c_void_p()
_Dll.doSomeThing(ctypes.byref(numberOfThings),ctypes.byref(indexes))
ptrt = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double*numberOfThings.value)
mydblPtr = cast(indexes, POINTER(c_double))
indexes = ptrt(mydblPtr.contents)`

In this case I will have following output of 
`TypeError: expected c_double_Array_3 instead of c_double`

for this line: 

`indexes = ptrt(mydblPtr.contents)`

Any idea :)?

Comment: Try casting defining the correct array type, so writing `mydblPtr = cast(indexes, POINTER(c_double*numberOfThings.value))`

Comment: (I updated my answer to make the solution readable and available to anyone :) )

Comment: I can now loop over the indexes :), the values I got are: `2.12199579097e-314
9.71636793692e-299
-6.98351003396e-251`. It should be 1,2,3. Is this some matter with ctypes?

Comment: There must be an issue in your DLL logic... it seems the values are all _near to_ 0, as if all values were initialized with `0.0` value. But it's hard to say without more implementation details.

Comment: I found it, should be c_int instead of c_double. I have updated the final solution in your answer!! Thx a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can start by making a pointer rather than an int32:

```
numberOfThings = ctypes.c_int32()
indices = ctypes.c_void_p()
_Dll.doSomeThing(ctypes.byref(numberOfThings), ctypes.byref(indices))
```

We can then convert the address into a properly typed pointer to an array (here assumed to be doubles):

```
ptrt = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double*numberOfThings.value)
indices = ptrt(indices.contents)

for n in indices.contents:
    print n
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I got `AttributeError: 'c_void_p' object has no attribute 'contents'` Should it not be enough with `from ctypes import *` to get conntents?

Comment: My mistake, Alex Gidan provided info on cast(). Try casting to ptrt instead of POINTER(c_double): `indices = ctypes.cast(indices, ptrt)`

Comment: Thx!! Ok, now I can loop :)! But still values seems to be kind of hard to evaluate :)

The code:

`ptrt = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double*numberOfThings.value)`

`indexes = ctypes.cast(indexes, ptrt)`

`indexes = ptrt(indexes.contents)` 

`print indexes`

`for n in indexes.contents:`
 `print n`
 
This will print out:

`<ctypes.LP_c_double_Array_3 object at 0x14490170>`

`2.12199579097e-314`

`4.37702459859e-299`

`-1.6068586969e-315`


I had hoped for more readable info :)?